# Regex not working for password? not sure why

Tags: php, regex, function, passwords, preg-match

So I have a regex code to make sure the password is from 4 to 13 characters, it keeps failing

```
public function valid_password($password){
        if(preg_match('^.{3,14}^', $password)){
            return true;
        }//end if
        else{
            return false;
        }//end else     
    }
```

I'm using regex and not php's length attribute because I will be adding more regex code later on. However, now I'm stuck with this failing program.

The problem is, it makes sure the password is over 3 characters however it doesn't care how long it is as if I have set no limit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^.{3,14}$/', $password)
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the anchor for the beginning of a string. The end of a string is delimited using `$`:

```
public function valid_password($password) {
    return preg_match('~^.{3,14}$~', $password);
}
```

But in this case I wouldn't use a regex, but the [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) function instead:

```
public function valid_password($password) {
    $length = strlen($password);
    return $length >= 3 && $length <= 14;
}
```

If you like hacking around to save you that line:

```
public function valid_password($password) {
    return isset($password[2]) && !isset($password[14]);
}
```

But really, why do you want to restrict password length to 14 characters? That way you prevent people from choosing really secure passwords. You probably should raise that limit.

Comment: "Sorry, but the function **length** is not in the online manual." Perhaps you meant `strlen`?

Comment: @Tomalak: Right you are! Sorry for that.

Comment: For PHP, use `strlen`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php. Also, make sure to `trim` the input. Now it will also return true for just spaces.

Comment: @nikic you say that 14 is not secure how much would you recommend

Comment: @Tom: Uhm, hard to say. I personally don't restrict maximum size at all. Passwords are normally saved using a hash with fixed size, so storage isn't a problem. But 100 chars as maximum should be okay. That should satisfy even the most paranoid people.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `^` as delimiters [php.net/mregexp.reference.delimiters.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) here:

```
^.{3,14}^
```

That's possible, but not a good idea in your case, because you need the `^` for its actual purpose. It matches the start of the subject normally. And to correctly count the length, yout need to do that. You also need the `$` end of subject meta character.

So basically:

```
preg_match('/^.{3,14}$/'
```

Now if you want to combine this regex with other match criteria, I would recommend this fancy assertion syntax:

```
preg_match('/(?=^.{3,14}$) (...)/x', $password)
```

This will allow you to specify something else in place of `...` - and keep the length check implicit.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
preg_match('/^.{3,14}$/', $password)
```

but regexp for counting string length?? = Overkill

Answer (score 1):

`^` matches the start of a string, not the end. `$` matches the end.

And you forgot your delimiters.

The full, fixed line is:

```
if (preg_match('/^.{3,14}$/', $password)) {
```

However, I *strongly* recommend that you instead use:

```
$len = strlen($password);
if ($len >= 3 && $len <= 14) {
```

instead, since regular expressions are completely overkill for this.